# p:ajax works fine except in celleditor

Tags: html, jsf, primefaces

i am trying to use p:ajax event="keyup" in datatable but couldn't get the results.  following code works f9 normally

```
<p:inputText id="txtVNo" value="#{Bean.txtVNo}" style="width: 68px; height: 26px; padding-bottom: 0;  border-radius: 0px;" type="number" required="true" readonly="#{Bean.locktxtVNo}" >
      <p:ajax event="keyup" listener="#{Bean.gridCalc(0, 'VNo')}" />
</p:inputText>
```

but when i try use the same code in datatable, it does not fire the gridCalc event

```
<p:column width="45">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputText value="FC Debit" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <p:cellEditor>
                                <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{result.FCAMTDR}" /></f:facet>
                                <f:facet name="input">
                                    <p:inputText id="txtGrdFCAmtDr" value="#{result.FCAMTDR}" style="width:95%;">
                                        <p:ajax event="keyup" listener="#{Bean.gridCalc(0, 'FC Amt Dr')}" />
                                    </p:inputText> </f:facet>
                            </p:cellEditor>
                        </p:column>
```

Data table

```
<p:dataTable var="result" id="detTable" widgetVar="detTable"
                            value = "#{Bean.detTable}"
                            paginator = "false"
                            scrollable="true"  rowIndexVar="rowindex"  scrollHeight="344" scrollWidth="auto"
                            scrollRows="9" liveScroll="false"
                            editable = "true"
                            editMode = "cell"
                        >
```

Bean Event

```
    public void gridCalc (int r, String i) {
        System.out.println("gridCalc : " + r + " @ " + i + ", " + txtVNo);
//        detTable.get(r).get("FCAMT");
    }
```

Comment: You forgot toe mention your PrimeFaces version? MyFaces or Mojarra? etc?

Comment: i am using primefaces 7.0 in a maven repository

Comment: you have edit mode ="cell" but I don't see your example wrapped in a CellEditor like: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/edit.xhtml

Comment: @Melloware i beg ur pardon, it was there but i forgot to quote in my example, i hv updated the code above

Comment: In your top one you call it with `listener="#{Bean.gridCalc(0, 'VNo')}"` but in your cell edit you are missing the params `listener="#{Bean.gridCalc}"` why??

Comment: @Melloware sorry again, but it was another method without parameters which existed in the project but i forgot to copy.  Any how i hv changed the a.m. code.

Comment: and thanx for ur precious time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `event="blur"` instead of `event="keyup"`.

Comment: Sorry, one other thing to add:  `<p:ajax event="blur" update="@this" ... `